# Android Tests Exception in Constructor NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing, android-espresso

After solving my issues with project structure and android tests it appears that another issue is coming, when I try to run my tests i get this exception:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testRegisterNaming (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app.view.LibraryActivity
at es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app.LibraryTest.<init>(LibraryTest.java:16)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite.<init>(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:34)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.<init>(AndroidTestSuite.java:43)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidJUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(AndroidJUnit3Builder.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:598)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:578)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:542)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:269)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
)
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestResult.runProtected(DelegatingTestResult.java:90)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:49)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:63)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:270)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

`testRegisterNaming` isn't even the constructor but at the stack trace it marks `LibraryTest.java:16` as the source of the Exception

Here it is the test suite code:

```
public class LibraryTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LibraryActivity> {

    private LibraryActivity libraryActivity;

    public LibraryTest() {
        super(LibraryActivity.class); //this is line 16
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        libraryActivity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testRegisterNaming() {
        Register r = new Register("Foobar", RegType.TextReg);
        assertEquals("Foobar",r.getName());
    }
}
```

As far as I have dealt with tests in Android this shouldn't be failing anywhere but it is in fact...I don't get to see where could it be failing!

Also, build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'

            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            }
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')

        androidTest {
            java{
                srcDirs 'src/androidTest/java'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591921/junit-framework-assertionfailederror-exception-in-constructor-java-lang-nocla

are you not showing all of your build.gradle file? it might be some dependency conflict

Comment: alright, I did it, just added the contrib lib with the excludes and also this line: `testApplicationId "es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app.test"` moved all test classes to *.app.test and it properly works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this post [junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591921/junit-framework-assertionfailederror-exception-in-constructor-java-lang-nocla) I tried adding the contrib lib with excludes like this:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
}
```

and also, moved all test classes to *.app.test package, set

```
testApplicationId "es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app.test"
```

and now it properly works!

Comment: Thank you so much! This line is what fixed it for me! `androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'`